# send() to specific client C WInSock

Tags: c, windows, winsock

How would I send to a specific client when I have multiple clients connected. I've thought of `sendto();` But I run all of them on the same socket and i am unsure of a way to store their addr for `sendto()`. SO maybe my way of accepting multiple clients isn't very good?

My Server Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library
#define _WIN32_WINNIT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET sock, newsock;
int c;
int clientnum;
struct sockaddr_in server, client;

DWORD WINAPI ProcessClient(LPVOID lpParam) {
    SOCKET newSock = (SOCKET)lpParam;
    // Send and receive data.
    char buf[256];
    char newbuf[256];
    char cnumchar[5];
    strcpy(buf, "Hello Client #: ");
    itoa(clientnum, cnumchar, 10);
    strcat(buf, cnumchar);
    sendto(newSock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, NULL, NULL);
    char sendbuf[256];
    strcpy(sendbuf, "a");
    while (1)
    {
        if (recv(newSock, newbuf, sizeof(newbuf), 0) == 0 || recv(newSock, newbuf, sizeof(newbuf), 0) == -1)  {
            printf("\nClient disconnected");
            clientnum--;
        }
        else if (send(newSock, sendbuf, sizeof(sendbuf), 0) == 0 || send(newSock, sendbuf, sizeof(sendbuf), 0) == -1) {
            printf("\nClient Disconnected!");
            clientnum--;
        }



    }

}

int main()
{

    printf("Initializing Winsock...\n");
    int ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("Initialization Failed. Error: %d", ret);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Initialized.\n");

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Could not create socket! Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    //textcolor(2);
    printf("Socket Created!\n");

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(3939);

    //bind
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Bind failed! Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(sock);
        getch();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Binded!\n");

    // listen
    if (listen(sock, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Listen failed! Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(sock);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Now Listening...\n");
    do {
        newsock = SOCKET_ERROR;
        do {
            newsock = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
        } while (newsock == SOCKET_ERROR);
        printf("Client Connected!");
        DWORD dwThreadId;
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, ProcessClient, (LPVOID)newsock, 0, &dwThreadId);
        clientnum++;
    } while (true);
```

return 0;
    }

Comment: You have one *listening* socket, but each connected client has its own *connection* socket (which is what `accept()` returned).  To send to a particular client, just use the right socket (the one `accept()` returned for that client).  You do, however, only have one global copy of `clientnum`, which may be causing confusion (when a thread reads it, it's value might not be the same as it was when the thread was created).

Comment: Ok i will look into using the different connection sockets thank you! And the clientnum thing works as intended and shows each client their corresponding client number. My only other issue is detecting client disconnects and clientnum--; doesn't work at all.

Comment: It seems to me that you're on the right track with listening within your main and handling the clients within separate threads. You're also passing the right socket to the thread to handle the client. If you want to send data from one client to another you may just need a global list of all your connected clients?

Comment: Don't you have problems with "recv()" in "ProcessClient()" ..???  you are performing potentially two recv's in the "if" statement (provided the first recv() does not return zero)... that means you will be losing whatever you read on your first "recv()".  You should do a recv(), save its return-code, then test it with the "if" statement.

Comment: True Tony I will change that today and check the return of whatever i save it to. And of a sort yes Lukas. I want to be able to tell which client is which and in the server program if i type 1 it sends a certain message ONLY to client 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would send data to a specific client by `send`ing it to a socket connected to that client.

Which is what you're already doing.